# a TCP client communicating with a server set on ESP8266-01

Tags: android, tcp, arduino, client, esp8266

I'm setting up a TCP/IP communication between an android app and an ESP8266 module connected to Arduino uno. I'm using AT commands to set up the server as follows:

AT+CWMODE=1  
AT+CIPMUX=1
AT+CIPSERVER=1,80
I get OK for each.

I want send an int to the app : 0 or 1 , the app read the int and then sends the text typed in the editText to the ESP8266

Now, here is my app code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv;
EditText txt;
EditText txt2;
Button b;
string response;
private static Socket s ;
private static PrintWriter printWriter;
String message="";
private static String ip="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView) ;
    txt2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

 }
 class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {        s= new Socket(ip,80);

                //READING THE INPUT

           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
           InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            while(in!=null) {
                 response = in.readLine();
            }
                //SENDING THE MESSAGE
            printWriter= new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            printWriter.write(message);
            printWriter.flush();
            post_send();


            // closing all connections
           // printWriter.close();
           // in.close();
           // s.close();


        }catch(IOException e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}
           return null;
    }
  }
    public void send_text(View v)
    {
        message= txt.getText().toString();
        ip=txt2.getText().toString();
        myTask mt = new myTask();
        mt.execute();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"MT 
        LAUNCHED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }

     public void post_send(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response 
         ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data 
        sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
```

I have 1 button to create the socket and receive any data and then send a text.

When I click on the button I get the following message on the serial monitor:

```
 0, connected
```

so I type:

```
 AT+CIPSEND=0,4
```

I get :

```
SEND OK
```

but none of the toasts show
help me? What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data 
     sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` No. You cannot just toast that there. You could place that statmenent in onPostExecute() of your AsyncTask though. But only call it if you are sure that the message was sent.

Comment: I removed the connect_server function and put it's content at the top of DoInBackground the app no longer crashes but still doesn't receive/send any data

Comment: Also tell what the server is going to do first if a new client connects. Will the server first send something to the client? Or will the server try to read a message/command from the client first? Tell us your protocol.

Comment: @greenapps done

Comment: One cannot display Toasts() in the doInBackGround of an AsyncTask. They make your app crash. If your app does not crash now then code flow does not reach that Toast.

Comment: `Also tell what the server is going to do first if a new client connects. Will the server first send something to the client? Or will the server try to read a message/command from the client first? Tell us your protocol. – greenapps 15 mins ago   ` Please give all info asked for!

Comment: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ` You did not place that Toast in an onPostExecute(). Please follow advises.

Comment: `I send the int 1 serial monitor : ` You want to send a ´1´ to the client. As a string or an integer? Further that is not enough as your client is trying to read a line. So send only text also. A string. Not an integer (consisting of four bytes). So the server should write-send a line too.

Comment: @greenapps so I did send 4 bytes and I got an ok but apparently it never reached the post_send()

Comment: You should not send four bytes. Send a text first in a line as the client tries to read a line. Your clients while loop is wrong. You should brake the loop if response==null.

Answer (score 0):

> s = new Socket(ip, 80);

If you execute that code in the onClick() of an onClickListener you will get an `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Which lets your app crash.

All internet code (also the connecting and reading) should be executed from a thread or AsyncTask.

Your writing is already in an AsyncTask. Which is the way to go.